# multiple query return error why?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

i want to query based on the sources, so i put the codition in my base query that it should query always based on the source, where the source value is stored in the variable $webAddress.

and if nothing is selected it should run the default query but it always returning me an weird error !

error message ---

[image]

so why i am getting this error, anyone knows how to solve this weird problem !

Thanks a lot in advanced.

[image]

> 2. at AbstractJsonSerializer ::jsonDecode ('{"took":291,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":10,"max_score":0.94276774,"hits":[{"_index":"myIndex","_type":"myType","_id":"p717ff3c9460bf8a52407d6e4a63f239dbeb052cf","_score":0.94276774,"_source":{
>      "content": "A beautiful backyard has become a suburban status symbol
>      much like a brand-new car in the driveway. Upgrading your outdoor
>      space is not only uplifti ......} in
>      vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Serializers/SmartSerializer.php
>      at line 39  +
> 3. at SmartSerializer ->deserialize ('{"took":291,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":10,"max_score":0.94276774,"hits":[{"_index":"myIndex","_type":"myType","_id":"p717ff3c9460bf8a52407d6e4a63f239dbeb052cf","_score":0.94276774,"_source":{
>      "content": "A beau ....}
>
>    4.at Transport ->performRequest ('GET', '/myType/content/_search', array('size' => '30'), array('query' => array('bool' => array('must'
>      => array(array('query_string' => array('default_field' => 'source', 'query' => 'aa.com', 'bb.com', 'cc.com'))))), 'sort' => array())) in
>      vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/AbstractEndpoint.php
>      at line 86  +
> 4. at AbstractEndpoint ->performRequest () in vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php at
>      line 1012  +

if i print the query which is executing i get ---

```
{
    "index": "myIndex",
    "type": "myType",
    "size": 30,
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "default_field": "source",
                            "query": "aa.com, bb.com, cc.com"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "sort": []
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP code you have inserted twice the `query/bool/must` combo. Simply remove the first one and you should be fine.

```
    $params = array(
        'index' => "myIndex",
        'type' => "myType",
        'xize' => 100,
        'body' => array(
            'query' => array(
                'bool' => array(
                    'must' => array(

                    )
                )
            ),
            'sort' => array()
        )
    );

    $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = array(
        'query_string' => array(
            'default_field' => 'source',
            'query' => implode(', ', array_column($webAddress, 'source'))
        )
    ):
```

Comment: hi val, thanks for your answer :), but i do that er error --- Syntax error
500 Internal Server Error - JsonDeserializationError

Comment: Weird, can you make sure your arrays are properly nested and you can update your question with properly formatted code, please, will be easier to read (and debug). Thx

Comment: i have update my question, can u kindly have a look :)

Comment: Actually, I've updated my answer to better reflect what you want to do. Please try again.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but somehow i am always getting that error, i have update my question again to explain it little more clear ...

Comment: You haven't updated your query the way I've shown in my answer (i.e. you have the `query_string` two times now), you need to remove the first one (i.e. `bool/must` must be empty at first). Please check again.

Comment: Val i actually have tried your solution, but i am always getting the same error, i have updated one last time, thank you so much for your time

Comment: Can you paste the full error you get, I only see part of it and it looks like a valid response.

Comment: I have the feeling this has nothing to do with the query, but more with PHP not being able to parse the JSON response. I see there are 10 hits in the response, so the query executed successfully. Something in the JSON (i.e. related to your document content) makes the `SmartSerializer` choke somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot Val for your great help :)